# how do i get a flash builder 4 window on my other monitor?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, eclipse, flexbuilder

I read online that with Eclipse (which FB is built in) you can reposition an editor onto a different screen however I am unable to do so.. I get an X whenever dragging it anywhere outside the main application frame.
I am on OSX.

Comment: Flash Builder is such a miserable piece of (work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported AFAIK.

You can, as a workaround, create a new window  (`Window`, `New Window`), move your desired document/editor into that window, and maximize the editor to hide the panels around it (`Cmd-M`).

Comment: That would be a useful enough alternative, unfortunately I don't seem to have that option in my 'Window' menu... I can get at 'new editor' by right clicking on the open files bar, but it just puts that right in the same row.

Comment: @Damon Sorry, I don't use Flash Builder. It's in the newest version of Eclipse (Java developer variant) -- you could try combining your Flash Builder modules with the newest Eclipse; otherwise you'd have to wait for a more recent release of Flash Builder.